# Writing a patcher application for automatic updates of certain files

Tags: c#

I've read a couple of questions and answers on SO before I finally decided to post the question myself.

My aim is to write a patcher, which checks certain content against some location with up-to-date files. It'd be best if it could download and upload as little as possible, but detect modified files and replace either complete files or - preferably - only binary deltas.

I thought about making checksums of chunks on the server-side and checking against them on the client and only getting those chunks, that have different checksums.

What I really want to know is the theoretical approach, because I read a bit into VCDIFF and other approaches, but I am not sure I understand them. Is there a common approach to this sort of question? Is the chunk-idea correct? How would I go about implementing it in C# or Java?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of files (text, binary) you can use a diff algorithm to narrow down the changes you have to send.

One of our interns has done a study on version control management, and he came up with a diff algorithm based on some studies. Maybe it is useful to you.

You can find some literature over here:

1. E. Myers, „An O(ND) Difference Algorithm and Its Variations,” Algorithmica, p. 15, 1986.
2. mmanela, „Diffplex,” http://diffplex.codeplex.com/releases/view/66796.

If you want to send over files, I would go at least for checksum and length, since these are most certainly unique.

You could create a format like

- filename
- checksum
- length

Post it to the server. Let it return the changes if:

1. The file wasn't on the client yet
2. The checksum or length is different

In all other cases, leave it.

Comment: This looks very interesting - thank you! But what I think I need, is to know how I'd go about a patcher. Would I create a checksum of the file or piece of it and compare it to some checksum string from a file, that I have created upfront on the server? This is what I don't understand yet, I think.

Comment: Alright .. so I'd let the patcher load a file containing checksums first. Then I'd read the checksum and date of the client-side file and download the file (or file-chunk), which has a different checksum. Sounds good - thank you :). I'll try that and mark it as the correct answer thereafter if you don't mind. Thanks for the help!